# Put elements into an array that I can then pass to my MVC partial view

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to throw anywhere from 2 elements and up into an array that I can then jQuery.Ajax post to my MVC controller.

My issue is how to put them into an acceptable array or object that I can then pass to the MVC partial view?

I have classes setup I think will work for the buttons and jQuery `btnMoveUp`, `btnMoveDown`

I need to pass the data-procedureid and data-sortid to my MVC controller.

And for **bonus points** another part I think I will be stuck on.  If they click the "Move Up" button.  I need to grab the element above it and switch their sort orders.  Or the "Move Down" button need to grab the element below it and switch their sort orders.

I'm hoping this will be as easy as `jQuery(".btnMoveDown").next(".btnMoveDown").attr("data-sortorder")` but i haven't tested this possibility.

Here is my future aJax:

```
$(".btnMoveUp").click(function () {
   var currSortOrder = jQuery(this).data('sortorder');
   // find the element above this one and grab the sort order
   // switch the sort orders
   $.ajax({
       url: "YourController/GetData",
       type: "get",
       data: // What can I pass here that my MVC partial view can then use?
       success: function (result) {
           $("#procedures").html(result);
       }
   });
}
```

Here is the code:

```
<ul class="commentlist">
    @{
        int i = 1;
        //foreach (var item in @Model.IPACS_Processes.IPACS_Procedures)
        foreach (var item in @Model.IPACS_Procedures)
        {
        <li class="span6">
            <img src="../../Images/thumbs/doc.png" alt="" class="pull-left" />
            <div class="comment-info">
                <h4>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("ViewProcedure", new { id = item.procedureID })">
                        @item.name</a></h4>
                <h5>
                    <small>Owner: </small><a href="javascript:void(0);">@item.owner</a></h5>
                <br />
                <p>
                    @item.description
                </p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    @if (i > 1)
                    {
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-small btnMoveUp" data-procedureid="@item.procedureID" data-sortorder="@i"><span class="iconfa-double-angle-up icon-white">
                        </span>Move Up</a> 
                    }

                    @if (i < @Model.IPACS_Procedures.Count)
                    {
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-small btnMoveDown" data-procedureid="@item.procedureID" data-sortorder="@i"><span class="iconfa-double-angle-down">
                        </span>Move Down</a>
                    }
                    @{i++;}
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <br style="clear: both;" />
        }
    }
</ul>
```

Here it is generated:

```
<ul class="commentlist">
        <li class="span6">
            <img src="../../Images/thumbs/doc.png" alt="" class="pull-left">
            <div class="comment-info">
                <h4>
                    <a href="/MasterList/ViewProcedure/123">
                        XYZ Process Server</a></h4>
                <h5>
                    <small>Owner: </small><a href="javascript:void(0);">Some Dude</a></h5>
                <br>
                <p>
                    Enter Description for XYZProcess Server Procedure
                </p>
                <br>
                <p>

                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-small btnMoveDown" data-procedureid="122" data-sortorder="1"><span class="iconfa-double-angle-down">
                        </span>Move Down</a>

                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <br style="clear: both;">
        <li class="span6">
            <img src="../../Images/thumbs/doc.png" alt="" class="pull-left">
            <div class="comment-info">
                <h4>
                    <a href="/MasterList/ViewProcedure/122">
                        XYZ2 Process Server</a></h4>
                <h5>
                    <small>Owner: </small><a href="javascript:void(0);">Some Dude</a></h5>
                <br>
                <p>
                    Enter Description for XYZ2 Process Server Procedure
                </p>
                <br>
                <p>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-small btnMoveUp" data-procedureid="123" data-sortorder="2"><span class="iconfa-double-angle-up icon-white">
                        </span>Move Up</a> 

                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-small btnMoveDown" data-procedureid="123" data-sortorder="2"><span class="iconfa-double-angle-down">
                        </span>Move Down</a>

                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <br style="clear: both;">
        <li class="span6">
            <img src="../../Images/thumbs/doc.png" alt="" class="pull-left">
            <div class="comment-info">
                <h4>
                    <a href="/MasterList/ViewProcedure/121">
                        XYZ3 Process Server</a></h4>
                <h5>
                    <small>Owner: </small><a href="javascript:void(0);">Some Dude</a></h5>
                <br>
                <p>
                    Enter Description for XYZ3 Process Server Procedure
                </p>
                <br>
                <p>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-small btnMoveUp" data-procedureid="124" data-sortorder="3"><span class="iconfa-double-angle-up icon-white">
                        </span>Move Up</a> 

                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-small btnMoveDown" data-procedureid="124" data-sortorder="3"><span class="iconfa-double-angle-down">
                        </span>Move Down</a>

                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <br style="clear: both;">
        <li class="span6">
            <img src="../../Images/thumbs/doc.png" alt="" class="pull-left">
            <div class="comment-info">
                <h4>
                    <a href="/MasterList/ViewProcedure/120">
                        XYZ4 Process Server</a></h4>
                <h5>
                    <small>Owner: </small><a href="javascript:void(0);">Some Dude</a></h5>
                <br>
                <p>
                    Enter Description for XYZ4 Process Server Procedure
                </p>
                <br>
                <p>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-small btnMoveUp" data-procedureid="125" data-sortorder="4"><span class="iconfa-double-angle-up icon-white">
                        </span>Move Up</a> 


                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <br style="clear: both;">

</ul>
```

Comment: What's the bonus point to US Dollar conversion ratio?

Comment: @Jonesy lol.  I follow this mathamatical equation for the conversion ratio.  I use the I R Poor equation for conversion which some out to be about $0.02 cents per point. =(

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually (literally) writing code like this right now.  I am using jQuery UI to do the drag/drop re-ordering.  (This code may be a little different then most other code examples).

jQuery/javascript

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  $(".ui-sortable-container").sortable({
    handle: ".handle",
    stop: function (event, ui)
    {
      AJAX.postRouteUpdate();
    }
  });

  var AJAX =
  {
    postRouteUpdate: function ()
    {
        // create object that matches MVC object
        // not case sensitive
        var request = {};
        request.routeIDs = [];
        var selector = ".ui-routes .ui-route";

        // for each of my objects grab the routeid
        // this is the new order of the routeids
        // send them all in, it's just easier on the backend
        // and allows for future multiple re-sorts before
        // sending the request to the server
        $(selector).each(function (index)
        {
            request.routeIDs.push($(this).data('routeid'));
            // update the title value, as I have mine numbered
            $(this).find('.title').text((index + 1).toString());
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Routes/UpdateSequence',
            data: JSON.stringify(request),
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (result) {
              $("#procedures").html(result);
              }            
        });
    }};
```

Model:

```
public class RouteUpdateModel()
{
  public IEnumerable<int> RouteIDs { get; set; }
}
```

Controllers

```
public ActionResult UpdateSequence(RouteUpdateModel model)
{
   this.db().UpdateSequence(model.RouteIDs);

   return this.Partial(model);
}
```

View

```
@Model RouteUpdateModel

@foreach (var routeID in model.RouteIDs)
{
  //do whatever
}
```